# How to make an object move from one point to another via coordinates?

Tags: java, 2d

I currently have a 2d game in which I am trying to move a .png image following certain coordinates. If I where to place this object at (0,0) and then try to move to (500,500), I could do the following:

```
public void move() {
    if (x < 500) {
        x += velocityX;
    }
    if (y < 500) {
        y += velocityY;
    }
}
```

This would work, but only because its a perfectly diagonal line. With that system, I can only move the object horizontally, vertically, or diagonally, but never in between. If I were to try something like:

```
public void move() {
    if (x < 500) {
        x += velocityX;
    }
    if (y < 400) {
        y += velocityY;
    }
}
```

The object would just move in a perfect diagonal angle until it reached 400 on the y axis, it would move horizontally for the last bit to reach 500 on the x axis. How would I make it so that I could move the object to any coordinates while following a straight path?

Comment: Arithmetic. Figure out the distance you want the object to move (on each axis); divide distances by the number of steps you want it to take; add to x and y respectively.

Comment: @khelwood Number of steps?

Comment: number of steps means after how many turns you want your image to be at top.

Answer (score 0):

To move perfect diagonally in your window, you must make sure that the ratio of `velocityX` and velocityY` should be like this,

```
 velocityX         width
-----------  =  -----------
 velocityY         height
```

in Your case if `width` is 500 , `height` is 400 and if `velocityX` is 5, then

```
 velocityY should be 4
```

Comment: That works when `velocityX = 5` and `velocityY = 4`, but not when `velocityX = 2` and `velocityY = 1.6` even though it's the exact same ratio and it's the result of that equation.

Comment: `4` is `int` while `1.6` is `float`. make all related variables as `float`, then it will work fine.